# Angular2 ngb-tabset tabchange event

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have created a sample angular 2 assignment, where i have used ngb-tabset(for creating tab views).

I encountered "**tabChange**" event of ngb-tabset where we can check of do some computation before moving to any other tab.

Same thing i wanted to achieve on clicking of an external button click. i.e. when clicking on the button, one should be able to do some operations and move to the respective tab.

Can someone help me for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there is `select` method, also tabset is exported as `exportAs:
 'ngbTabset'`. All you need is:

```
<ngb-tabset #tasbset="ngbTabset" ...>
<button (click)="tasbset.select('id')" ...>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted. On top of this the exact scenario is demonstrated in the documentation - check the "Select an active tab by id" section at http://localhost:9090/#/components/tabs

Comment: Thanks for the help. I observed one thing here. After closing the model and opening it again, the activeId of the tabset is different, than the one open for the first. So as per my understanding, do we manually have to reset the tabset again ?

Comment: i guess component is recreated in this case, so you need to save last selected tab somewhere and restore it.

Comment: Ok. But can't we just refresh/reset the entire component ?